# how HttpServletResponse process by browser

Tags: java, http, servlets

In a servlet application web server forwards a HttpServletResponse to the browser right?
Then browser will render it and show the html.

But What is the exact type of the Response object browser expected? Is it HttpResponse? Then how come different type of object getting process?

I am bit confuse of the HttpServletResponse in the browser. Can please elaborate and explain it?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the exact type of the Response object browser expected?

A byte stream conforming to the HTTP 1.0 or 1.1 protocol for responses.

> Is it HttpResponse?

No, it is a byte stream conforming to the HTTP 1.0 or 1.1 protocol for responses.

> Then how come different type of object getting process?

This sentence does not parse. Try again.

Comment: so HttpResponse it not a object actually as you said a byte stream. Http Response is just a name for that byte stream which browser received. am i right?

Comment: My confusion was ok inside a servlet doGet method we get PrintWriter from HttpServletResponse like below,                                           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");     Then what happen is the server container creates a byte stream reading those println's and send that byte stream to server?  Does it a correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequest is a http element which is used to transfer data from client to server. HttpResponse is http element which is used to transfer data from server to client.

The response is basically sent inside a HttpResponse. HttpResponse is sent as binary data through network channels.

HttpResponse object has the followings;

- Protocol/Version, Status Code, and its Description
- HTTP Response Headers
- HTTP Response Body

I think, you are asking how different type of objects such as images, audios or videos are sent and interpreted by browsers. Browsers understands the file types by mime types inside http response headers, then interpret its content.

See also

[MIME Types](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Comment: This is misleading.  It suggests that the HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects are sent between the client and server.  In fact, it is the information content of the objects that is sent.  At the far end, the browser may (or may not) use some kind of object to represent the request or response.  But the chances are that they *won't* be Java objects at all.

Comment: you are right. i edited my post accordingly. I did not refer to HttPServletRequest or HttpServletResponse in my post. @StephenC